# Открытие ассоциированных с программой файлов в уже запущенном экземпляре программы (вместо запуска нового)

Tags: c#, .net

Для того, чтобы открыть ассоциированный файл, программа проверяет при запуске были ли переданы в нее какие-либо параметры. Для простоты можно представить, что открывается текстовый файл.

```
 private static void Main(string[] args)
 {
   if(args != null && args.Length > 0)
   {
     string fileName = args[0];
     // дальше что-то делаю с файлом
   }
 }
```

Проблема в следующем. Если я открываю с помощью проводника очередной файл, то открывается новая копия программы, а мне надо, чтобы файл открывался в уже открытой копии, если она есть или открывал, если нет.

Comment: я никогда этим не занимался, но подозреваю, что в таком случае программа должна найти свою уже запущенную копию и передать ей тем или иным способом путь к этому файлу для открытия

Comment: да, я то же это так вижу, но не хочется изобретать велосипед, уверен должны быть какие-то стандартные решения

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Есть следующий способ запуска только одной сущности любого .NET приложения:

1. При запуске создаем и пытаемся залочить мьютекс. Если это удалось --
   это первый инстанс приложения. Если взять лок не удалось -- значит,
   наше приложение уже запущено (поскольку мьютекс является объектом ОС
   и шарится между всеми процессами).
2. Если мы обнаружили, что приложение уже запущено, нам нужно передать
   сообщение (в вашем случае -- путь к файлу) запущенному процессу. Это
   можно сделать любым из способов межпроцессорного взаимодействия:
   сообщения Windows, веб-сервис и т.д.
3. При любом выходе из приложения (нормальном или аварийном) не
   забываем освобождать мьютекс.
4. Пример правильного использования мьютекса -- [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/229567/1985167).

В случае Windows Forms приложения есть более простой способ, описанный на [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/424427/1985167).