# Синхронизация процессов и обмен сообщениями без блокировки потока ожиданием

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Есть код который отслеживает, что будет запущен только один экземпляр приложения. При попытке запустить второй экземпляр уже запущенный экземпляр получает фокус. Это реализуется через отдельный поток.

Интересует можно ли здесь как то использовать поток из пула (`Task`) и/или `await/async`? И как сообщить уже запущенному приложению, что была попытка еще одного запуска, а также передать аргументы командной строки из этого второго запуска (нужно для некоторой логики)?

`OnlySingleInstance()` вызывается при старте приложения. Первый экземпляр при старте создвает `EventWaitHandle`. При попытке запустить второй экземпляр, в нем будет вызван `Set()` и этот экземпляр завершит свою работу. Первый экземпляр получит сигнал о том, что была попытка запустить еще один экземпляр приложения и покажет свое главное окно.

```cs
private static EventWaitHandle currentApplicationEventWaitHandle;
private static Thread signalThread;

public static void OnlySingleInstance(this Application application)
{    
    var appKey = "uniq app key";

    if (EventWaitHandle.TryOpenExisting(appKey, out var eventWaitHandle))
    {
        // try to start another app instance

        eventWaitHandle.Set();
        application.Shutdown(1);

        return;
    }

    // app first run

    eventWaitHandle = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.AutoReset, appKey);
    currentApplicationEventWaitHandle = eventWaitHandle;

    application.Exit += OnApplicationExit;

    signalThread = new Thread(() =>
    {
        while (eventWaitHandle.WaitOne())
        {
            // show main window
        }    
    });

        signalThread.IsBackground = true;
        signalThread.Start();
}

public static void DisableSingleInstanceWatcher()
{
    signalThread?.Abort();
    currentApplicationEventWaitHandle?.Close();
}

private static void OnApplicationExit(object sender, ExitEventArgs e)
{
    DisableSingleInstanceWatcher();
}
```

Comment: Поток из пула - легко `Task.Run(() => { while (eventWaitHandle.WaitOne()) { ... } });` что касается асинхронного вызова, нужно сначала понять, почему ваш код сделан именно так, и как это работает. Я когда-то использовал `Mutex` и WinAPI для таких дел, то есть совсем по-другому реализовал без каких-либо потоков, могу показать, как.

Comment: @aepot, я добавил описание как работает код. Если использовать Task.Run(), как предложили Вы, то мы все равно будем иметь поток, который живет все время работы приложения. Мне интересно, можно ли уйти от отдельного потока для этой задачи.

Comment: Можно, я же написал выше, `Mutex`+WinAPI, могу показать как.

Comment: Вы выбрали неправильны объект сихронизации. Надо не события слать, а использовать именованны mutex, и на старте экземпляра проверять, не держит ли этот mutex уже существующий экземпляр. Если держит - сразу выходить. Вот пример: https://stackoverflow.com/a/819808/1988244 (там в комментариях про abandoned mutex exception есть, но для мьютекса, который захватывается главным потоком, это не принципиально)

Comment: @PashaPash, а как сообщить уже запущенному приложению, что была попытка еще одного запуска, а также передать аргументы командной строки из этого второго запуска (нужно для некоторой логики).

Comment: @ВиталийЕфимов посмотрите https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/668138/177221, там есть ответ про NamedPipes - в примере прокидывается один байт (100), но можно прокинуть что угодно.

Comment: @PashaPash блин, большое спасибо, я только что написал нормальный такой ответ с асинхронностью и без `Task.Run()`, 40 минут писал, а вы закрыли вопрос.

Comment: @aepot так полный дубликат жеж :)

Comment: @PashaPash, не очень и дубликат. Задача запуска одного экземпляра приложения мною решена, но в ее решении присутствует поток, который заблокирован почти все время через eventWaitHandle.WaitOne(). Вот и интересует наличие способа уйти от использования этого потока.

Comment: От потока чисто технически на низком уровне уйти не получится, но от синхронной блокировки - вполне. Если вопрос разблокируют, добавлю сюда пример, как это можно сделать.

Comment: @aepot так может в тот вопрос ответ запостить?

Comment: @ВиталийЕфимов способ уйти от использования потока - использовать правильный объект синхронизации. Потому что как только вы попробуете не просто сообщить о запуске, а еще и передать аргументы командной строки - вам придется поменять eventWaitHandle на что-то, что позволяет передавать данные, а не просто факт запуска. И вы получите решение с Mutex + NamedPipeServerStream. Для NamedPipeServerStream не обязателен поток, там есть асинхронное API, но код получится объемнее синхронного вызова.

Comment: @PashaPash он не подходит, там про свернутое приложение, а мой код про передачу аргументов. Поэтому я проголосовал за переоткрытие.

Comment: @aepot там есть ответы с передачей аргументов. Тут в вопросе нет ничего про передачу аргументов. Какой смысл переоткрывать вопрос-дубликат, ради ответа, который просто дополняет ответ в другом вопросе? Запостите туда, всем будет полезнее - и автору вопроса, и другим посетителям - т.к. на этот вопрос Гугл точно не выведет.

Comment: @PashaPash ну гугл не только по вопросам ищет, но и по ответам. Я починил вопрос, так лучше?

Comment: @aepot да, но imho все равно все варианты запуска лучше было бы собрать в одном вопросе, а не плодить чуть отличающиеся по принципу "тут надо передать аргументы/тут не надо/тут надо только окно открыть". Дубликат с небольшой вариацией - все равно дубликат. Ответ в существующем вопросе был бы полезнее.

Comment: @aepot И чем ваш ответ отличается от того ответа? Технологии одни, все почти одно и тоже, отличие лишь в том, что у вас чуть более подробнее ответ. ИМХО, опять ерундой какой-то страдаете и ради своих ответов готовы аж суть вопроса изменить и подстроить его под себя, ну не хорошо так. Если на SO есть уже похожее, то дополняйте его, а не делайте дубликат!

Comment: @EvgeniyZ принял к сведению, спасибо.

Comment: @aepot Ох не думаю, сколько раз мы на этой почве бодались и? Опять вы делаете дубликат... Хотяб объясните свою логику. Вот просто давайте разберем два ответа `new Mutex` - есть, `mutex.WaitOne` - есть, `new NamedPipeClientStream` - есть, `stream.Connect` - есть,  `stream.Write` - есть, `stream.WaitForConnection` - есть. И это по-вашему не дубликат? Вы максимум здесь прикрутили асинхронность, но суть тажа. Ну и к чему тогда было переоткрытие? Дайте мне вас понять, прошу... Если человек спросит "как передать число в другую копию", что, делать будем еще один ответ, но уже не JSON, а `int`?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ я бы не смог в одиночку переоткрыть вопрос. Я не намерен продолжать мусолить эту "проблему" в комментариях. Задайте вопрос на Мете, если это так важно, обсудим все вместе.

Comment: @aepot Переоткрытие было по вашей просьбе участником tym32167, видать ему понравился ваш комментарий про "это не дубликат". Поэтому я и спрашиваю вас, почему это не дубликат? Я вам дал весомые поводу обратного, но вы всячески пытаетесь слезть с темы. Ок, буду поступать иначе, впредь, если я увижу, что вы ленитесь искать дубликаты, отвечаете на все подряд и игнорируете правила SO, то я просто буду на такие ответы кидать минусы от себя, ибо я против такого на SO! Если вы считаете иначе, повторюсь, я жду от вас хоть одного внятного объяснения почему этот ответ должен быть тут.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Я тот дубликат нашел еще раньше, чем его здесь запостил PashaPash, но он содержит устаревший код, на момент ответа (2017 год) еще не было асинхронных API там, где надо. Вопрос в референсе задан только про разворачивания приложения, к чему мой ответ буквально не имеет никакого отношения. Да, технически ответ очень схож с существующим, я больше вам скажу, я его брал за основу при разработке приложения-ответа. То что технологии используются грубо говоря те же самые, не значит, что они используются для решения одной и той же задачи. На бизнес уровне задачи разные.

Comment: @aepot Так вы ведь сами сказали "нашли дубликат", то, что дубликат устарел, это не отменяет тот факт, что он "дубликат". SO открытая платформа, вы всегда можете отредактировать старые ответы, а можете там написать новые, вам не запрещают, но вы плодите бесмысленные для базы SO вопросы и по вашей логике, мы каждую новую версию C# и другого языка, должны делать новый вопрос с новыми ответами, а не обновлять старое. Вот серьезно, вам даже бывшый модератор вон выше говорит, что для SO лучше подобное собрать в одном месте, но вы уперто пытаетесь спасти вопрос, дав на него ответ, еще и переоткрыли..

Comment: @EvgeniyZ я ваше мнение и с первого раза понял, можно не разжевывать. Еще раз - [идёте на Мету](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions), создаёте вопрос, и мы там будем его обсуждать до тех пор, пока он не решится, ну или создайте чат. **Комментарии не предназначены для рассширенных дискуссий.** Вы призываете меня к порядку, когда сами к нему относитесь весьма однобоко. Нехорошо.

Comment: @aepot Я считаю, что это ваша проблема, вашего нежелания следовать правилам и не хочу этот спор делать общим. Я попытался узнать почему вы так делаете, в ответ получаю то, что противоречит всем уставам SO, говорю, что вы не правы, но вы даете заднюю. Смысл мне сидеть с вами в чате и разжовывать? Не понимаете, буду минусовать, ведь минус это что? Несогласие с ответом, а я не согласен созданием дубликатов на SO. А по поводу "относитесь весьма однобоко" - данные комментарии мало кому помешают, даже больше скажу, их потрут, а ответ, увы, на SO забивают на такое.

Comment: @aepot ну ок, вот полный дубликат по бизнес требованиям: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/413057/ - открыть и передать параметры командной строки.

Comment: @PashaPash он самый, но я его не нашел.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Покажу пример, который демонстрирует:

- Как использовать `Mutex` для контроля количества запущенных копий приложения.
- Как передать аргументы от одного процесса другому через Named Pipe.
- Как реализовать такой код асинхронно, чтобы не было синхронной блокировки в потоках.

Приложение проверяет, было ли оно запущено повторно, если было, то отправляет свои аргументы основной запущенной копии приложения и завершается.

```cs
class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        using Mutex mutex = new Mutex(true, "MyMutex");
        if (!mutex.WaitOne(500, false))
        {
            using (NamedPipeClientStream stream = new NamedPipeClientStream("MyPipe"))
            {
                using StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(stream);
                await stream.ConnectAsync();
                await sw.WriteLineAsync(JsonSerializer.Serialize(args));
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Программа уже запущена.");
            Console.ReadKey(true);
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            using CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
            Task task = RunMessageServer(cts.Token);
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Привет, это первая копия программы!");
                Console.ReadKey(true);
                Console.WriteLine("Завершение работы...");
            }
            finally
            {
                cts.Cancel();
                using NamedPipeClientStream stream = new NamedPipeClientStream("MyPipe");
                stream.Connect(); // вот этот костыль необходим, чтобы разморозить WaitForConnectionAsync, и чтобы сработала отмена
                mutex.ReleaseMutex();
            }
            await task;
            Console.WriteLine("Готово.");
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }

    private static async Task RunMessageServer(CancellationToken token)
    {
        using NamedPipeServerStream stream = new NamedPipeServerStream("MyPipe");
        using StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream);
        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                await stream.WaitForConnectionAsync(token);
                string json = await sr.ReadToEndAsync();
                if (json.Length > 0)
                {
                    string[] args = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<string[]>(json);
                    Console.Write("Программа была запущена повторно ");
                    if (args.Length > 0)
                        Console.WriteLine("с аргументами: " + string.Join(", ", args));
                    else
                        Console.WriteLine("без аргументов");
                }
                stream.Disconnect();
            }
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException) { } // сработал токен отмены
    }
}
```

Запускаю несколько копий:

```
ConsoleApp1.exe
ConsoleApp1.exe
ConsoleApp1.exe весомые аргументы
```

Вывод первой запущеной копии приложения:

```
Привет, это первая копия программы!
Программа была запущена повторно без аргументов
Программа была запущена повторно с аргументами: весомые, аргументы
Завершение работы...
Готово.
```

Вывод остальных копий одинаковый:

```cs
Программа уже запущена.
```