# Десктопное приложение c# - проблема с dll и System.Devices

Tags: c#, windows, dll, x86-64

у меня есть приложение, работающее с удалённым девайсом(сканером) через блютус, в котором возникла проблема по работе в x64 разрядных системах, а конкретно доступ к Dll `RAPI2` и `System.Device`, я также не могу использовать пространство имён `using System.Devices` что соответственно влечет за собой недоступность типов имён `RemoteDeviceManager`, `RemoteDevice` и т.д.

Вопрос: существует ли аналог для x64разрядных систем? или есть способ использовать x32 разрядные dll для x64 разрядных систем

Я нагуглил про установку `Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contacts` NuGet пакет, но это не помогло

Comment: Можно написать свой 32 битную обертку над dll, В главном приложении вызывать этот процесс. Общение между процессами можно сделать на grpc или чем то другим.

Comment: @Vasek Можете направить куда смотреть по этим пунктам лучше? с такими методами я не сталкивался

Comment: Просто напишите 32-битное приложение, использующее API библиотеки и стартуете его как дочерний `Process`, который будет принимать команды от основного приложения и отправлять необходимые данные. Для передачи данных между процессами можно использовать например Named Pipe, [вот здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1230878/373567) есть очень простой пример. Или GRPC, как выше советуют. Или [вот еще вариант](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3037438/12888024) с COM.