# С# подцепить TimeOut к Stream(Writer)?(Reader)?

Tags: c#, io, timeout, pipes

Есть `NamedPipe` со службой для `Windows` (также на C#).
Что на стороне сервера, что на стороне клиента есть объекты `StreamReader` и `StreamWriter`:

```
private StreamReader reader;
private StreamWriter writer;

public NPipeClient()
{
    NamedPipeClientStream client = new NamedPipeClientStream(".", "GDSPipe", PipeDirection.InOut, PipeOptions.Asynchronous);
    client.Connect();

    this.reader = new StreamReader(client);
    this.writer = new StreamWriter(client);
}
```

И я представляю ситуацию, когда данные ушли с клиента, а сервис в этот момент умирает и в таком случае клиент будет бесконечно ждать репла со стороны сервера, что мне абсолютно не нужно.

Пытался сделать вот так:

```
this.reader.BaseStream.ReadTimeout = 3000;
this.writer.BaseStream.WriteTimeout = 3000;
```

Но, как и ожидалось:

```
Вызвано исключение: "System.InvalidOperationException" в mscorlib.dll
Необработанное исключение типа "System.InvalidOperationException" в mscorlib.dll
Данный поток не поддерживает таймауты.
```

В остальных случаях нашел только асинхронную кашу, но, уверен кто-нибудь посоветует вариант по-лучше.

Comment: Возможно [этот пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1230878/373567) поможет или что-то объяснит.

Comment: Попробуйте использовать поток асинхронно с `CancellationToken` и канселить его по таймауту.

Comment: `var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource(3000);
await namedPipeClientStream.ReadAsync(memory, cancellationTokenSource.Token);` - не?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov `using (var cancellationTokenSource = ...) { ... }`

Comment: Понял, спасибо @aepot и AlexanderPetrov