# Можно ли передать файл в запущенное приложение через командную строку?

Tags: c#, cmd

уважаемое сообщество.
Суть в следующем: есть запущенный процесс "DIALux.exe", который через drag-and-drop принимает в себя фотометрические файлы формата *.ies. И у меня возник вопрос, можно ли реализовать тот же самый drag-and-drop посредством командной строки, зная путь к файлу и номер процесса.
Или, например, используя C#, через процесс передать объект файла.
Если кто-нибудь сталкивался с чем-то подобным, прошу отписаться.

Решение через PostMessage нашлось вот тут
https://studassistent.ru/charp/kak-programmno-emulirovat-drag-drop-fayla-na-okno-storonnego-prilozheniya-c
С той лишь поправкой, что работает для случая с "notepad.exe", но не работает для "DIALux.exe". Видимо потому что в DIALux перетаскивание осуществляется на определенные элементы.

Comment: drag-and-drop предполагает работу мышкой. У процесса `"DIALux.exe"` есть открытое окошко куда вы мышкой кидаете файл `формата *.ies`?

Comment: Вы говорите о том, что drag-and-drop делается в проводнике, перетаскивая файл в другой файл формата `.exe`? Если да, то Windows передаст таким образом путь к файлу в качестве аргумента. В консольном приложении, если вы замечали, функция `main` принимает `string[] args`. Вот в этом массиве и появится путь к файлу (`args[0]`), который вы передали в `exe`

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Синхронизация процессов и обмен сообщениями без блокировки потока ожиданием](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1230746/%d0%a1%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%85%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%86%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bc)

Comment: Да, у процесса есть окно, куда происходит перетаскивание. И я понимаю, что в приложении описаны события реагирующие на данные перетаскивания. Если бы нужно было запустить приложение с некими стартовыми аргументами, тогда было бы все просто, но вот как передать те самые аргументы активному процессу для меня пока загадка. Если использовать c# то может кто знает в какой объект "пихать" передаваемый файл? Или тут надо попробовать отрыть в библиотеках приложения нужный класс и кастовать через Marshal.GetActiveObject() как обычно делают с САПР?

Comment: В голову приходит поискать хэндл окна (**FindWindow**). А затем направить в него файл с помощью **PostMessage**. А простому эникейщику можно и заскриптовать это действо утилитами вроде **AutiIt**

Comment: Используйте утилиту Spy++, чтобы определить хэндлы окон в приложении DIALux. Далее в PostMessage указываете нужный хэндл.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov большое спасибо, что рассказали про Spy++, попробовал прокинуть во все возможные хэндлы, не прокатило, буду пробовать записывать сообщения процесса при перетаскивании