# Как сделать запуск массива байтов в памяти без записи на диск?

Tags: c#

В общем у меня есть base64 картинка и я её декрипчу получаю массив байтов и могу ли я без записи на диск открыть эту картинку?

Comment: Да и в чем проблема? Открыть только в вашем понимании это?

Comment: запустить я имею виду, чтобы открылось окно с картинкой.

Comment: можете, только черт его знает, что у вас за приложение, от этого зависит то, какую именно библиотеку надо использовать.

Comment: консольное c#. Просто запустить бинарный код в памяти, как я понял.

Comment: ну если консольное, то вам либо на диск надо сохранять и открывать с помощью другого приложения, какого-нибудь просмотрщика, либо добавлять компоненты Windows Forms и делать свое окно. А `Bitmap` из массива, чтобы показать в своем окне, [можно легко создать](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21555394/how-to-create-bitmap-from-byte-array) с помощью GDI+ библиотеки `System.Drawing`.

Comment: То есть подключаете Windows.Forms, запускаете приложение, которому передаете созданный `Bitmap`, а в окне `PictureBox` размером со всё окно должен быть. Ему и недо отдать как источник данных созданный `Bitmap`.

Comment: Ну или сразу пересоздайте проект как Winforms или WPF и перенесите код туда. В WPF правда немного другая библиотека для работы с картинками. Но WPF прикольно то, что можно вообще создать в XAML разметке Image и привязать его с свойству в коде, содержащему массив байт, и оно само заработает без лишнего кода.

Comment: тоесть в c# нельзя запустить массив байтов, без сохранения на диск?

Comment: Запустить куда? В космос? Массив - это данные, их можно либо читать, либо писать. Запустить можно только код. Вам что именно нужно? Если вы хотите, чтобы стороннее приложение залезло в память к вашему приложению и прочитало в нем массив, то это невозможно.

Comment: Есть еще вариант: пишете второе приложение, которое может принимать данные [например через Named Pipe](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1230878/373567), запускаете его через Process.Start, подключаетесь к нему через Pipe и передаете данные. Есть и другие способы, но все они упираются в то, что приложение-просмотрщик картинок должно быть написано вами. Если нужен стандартный просмотрщик, то без записи на диск не получится.

Comment: Вас может быть сбил с толку тот факт, что при клике в картинку открывается просмотр, типа запуск картинки. Но на самом деле это не запуск картинки, а запуск приложения просмотрщика с передачей ему пути на картинку в качестве аргумента. Данные нельзя запустить, потому что они не код, запустить можно только код.

Comment: окей понял, тогда попробую по другому.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
using System.Windows.Forms; //не забыть подключить ссылку
using System.Drawing;

void openviewer(byte[] data)
{
    Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(new MemoryStream(data));
    Form f = new Form() { BackgroundImage = bitmap };
    f.Show();
}
```

И вызывайте функцию openviewer из своего консольного приложения.