# Обмен данными между процессами

Tags: c#, память, memory-management

Как можно имея один буфер (memory-mapped file) отправлять и получать сообщения между процессами? Получается буфер это просто пространство и нужно изобретать протокол взаимодействия с ним? Сокеты не предлагать)

Comment: Верно, MMF просто общий кусок памяти. Для общения понадобятся ещё средства межпроцессного общения - например, события (events)  в простейшем случае. Кстати, пайпы, сокеты и т.п. в пределах одного компа основаны на тех же MMF

Comment: Named Pipes? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1230878/373567

Comment: Уточните: вас интересует как именно использовать MMF или какие есть способы межпроцессного взаимодействия?