# Передать строку из одного процесса в другой

Tags: c#, windows, .net

У меня есть консольное приложение: "лаунчер". Оно запускает другое приложение:

```
var p = new Process
{
    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("thesecond.exe")
    {
        UseShellExecute = true
    }
};
if(p.Start())
{
    p.WaitForExit();
    // here I need some info from the thesecond.exe
}
```

Это другое приложение должно сгенерировать некую строку, которую мне нужно получить в лаунчере. Как я могу передать эту строку из созданного процесса в создающий, максимально просто и не замусоривая систему?

Comment: Генератор пишет в консоль, через console.write/writeline.   Лаунчер читает вывод генератора. Вывод можно получить прям через procces.

Comment: Vasek, Генератор не консольный, это стороннее винформ-приложение. Но я него могу вставить кусочек кода как плагин.

Comment: Например [через Named Pipe](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1230878/373567).

Comment: Способов много, но имхо, самый простой (если у вас оба приложения .net) - подключить и использовать второе приложение как dll (даже если оно .exe). Потом запустить его через: ``TheSecondForm tsf = new TheSecondForm(); tsf.Show();`` И вы спокойно и без всяких проблем сможете гонять любые данные, обращаться к public свойствам/полям, вызывать public методы приложения ``thesecond`` - из своего лаунчера. В обратную сторону это так-же работает с использованием делегатов/событий/ссылок на методы и функции лаунчера. По опыту говорю, что это самое простое, быстрое и надёжное решение без костылей.

Comment: PS Стоит учесть, что в таком случае ``thesecond.exe`` не запускается как отдельный процесс, а запускается как сборка в процессе-родителе (лаунчере). Описание технологии: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/app-domains/application-domains

Comment: aepot, да, это работает. Спасибо за идею!

Comment: Смотрите [Inter-process communication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) / [Межпроцессное взаимодействие](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Межпроцессное_взаимодействие). Есть множество способов. Самый рекомендуемый - именованные каналы.

Comment: Всем спасибо за подсказки! Остановился на пайпах, работает.