# Как переместить всё содержимое list box в list box 2?

Tags: c#, winforms

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
my program cs
using Laba_6;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace lab6
{
    class Program
    {
        public string ident;
        public string Ident
        {
            get { return ident; }
            set { ident = value; }
        }
        public string pib;
        public string PIB
        {
            get { return pib; }
            set { pib = value; }
        }

        public string number;
        public string Number
        {
            get { return number; }
            set { number = value; }
        }

        public string sume;
        public string Sume
        {
            get { return sume; }
            set { sume = value; }
        }



        public Program(string i, string p, string n, string s)
        {
            ident = i;
            pib = p;
            number = n;
            sume = s;
        }

        public Program()
        {
        }

        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());


            List<Program> account = new List<Program>();

            account.Add(new Program("220653", "", "+380505944873", "100000"));

            foreach (Program obj in account)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Identification number - " + obj.ident + " PIB" + obj.pib + " Number - " + obj.number + " Sume - " + obj.sume + "\n");
            }

            

        }
    }
}

form 1 cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace Laba_6
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void TabPage1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void TabPage1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Close();
        }

        private void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }



        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void TabPage1_Click_2(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void tabPage1_Click_3(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Close();
        }

        private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Clear();
        }

        private void button3_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            

       
            lab6.Program account = new lab6.Program();
            account.Ident = textBox1.Text;
            account.PIB = textBox2.Text;
            account.Number = textBox3.Text;
            account.Sume = textBox4.Text;

           
                listBox1.Items.Add("Номер рахунку - " + account.Ident + " ПІП - " + account.PIB + " Телефон - " + account.Number + " Сума - " + account.Sume);
                MessageBox.Show("Аккаунт успішно доданий");
            
        }

        private void tabPage2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Close();
        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


        }

        private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        private void list_box2(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


        }

        private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void label3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button4_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lab6.Program account = new lab6.Program();
            account.Ident = textBox8.Text;
            account.PIB = textBox7.Text;
            account.Number = textBox6.Text;
            account.Sume = textBox5.Text;
            listBox2.Items.Add("Номер рахунку - " + account.Ident + " ПІП - " + account.PIB + " Телефон - " + account.Number + " Сума - " + account.Sume);
            MessageBox.Show("Аккаунт успішно доданий");
        }

        private void radioButton2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            lab6.Program account = new lab6.Program();
            listBox2.Items.Add(listBox1.SelectedItem);
            listBox1.Items.Remove(listBox1.SelectedItem);

            MessageBox.Show("Аккаунт успішно доданий");

        }

        private void listBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button6_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
            lab6.Program account = new lab6.Program();
            listBox2.Items.Add(listBox1.Text);

          
            MessageBox.Show("Аккаунт успішно доданий");


        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Linq;
using System.IO.Pipes;
using System.Threading;

internal sealed class MainThreadServer
{
    [STAThread]
    private static void Main()
    {
        Thread serverThread = new Thread(StartServerThread);
        serverThread.Start();

        Thread clientThread = new Thread(StartClientThread);
        clientThread.Start();
    }

    private static void StartServerThread()
    {
        const string message = "Hello, world!";

        using NamedPipeServerStream server = new NamedPipeServerStream("server");
        server.WaitForConnection();
        Console.WriteLine("Найдено новое подключение...");

        byte[] buffer = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(message);
        server.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    }

    private static void StartClientThread()
    {
        using MainThreadClient client = new MainThreadClient();

        client.Connect("server");
        Console.WriteLine("Подключен!");
        Console.WriteLine($"SERVER: {client.GetContext()}");
    }
}

internal sealed class MainThreadClient : IDisposable
{
    private NamedPipeClientStream Client;

    public void Connect(string nameServer)
    {
        Client = new NamedPipeClientStream(nameServer);
        Client.Connect();
    }

    public string GetContext()
    {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(Client))
        {
            string line = string.Empty;
            while ((line = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
                stringBuilder.Append(line);
        }

        byte[] buffer = stringBuilder.ToString().ToCharArray().Select(x => (byte)x).ToArray();
        return Encoding.Default.GetString(buffer);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Client.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Я конечно понимаю, что здесь и так все понятно, но лучше бы было, если вы бы привели пример с интеграцией в винформы. И этот сервер обработает всего одно входящее подключение и завершится. А еще он крашнет приложение на строке `server.WaitForConnection()`, если никто не подключится до выхода из серверного ожидания.

Comment: А что это такое ?

Comment: Можете пожалуйста помочь с моим вопросом

Comment: @aepot если не кто не подключился, до выхода из серверного ожидания - ничего страшного. По завершению вы должны все подключения вручную уничтожать. При новом подключении, вы должны передавать объект подключения новой задачи, для асинхронной обработки клиентов.

Comment: @MRXIT чтобы прервать выполнения метода `server.WaitForConnection();`, нужно чтобы он принял подключение. Вы же не можете ему сказать, чтобы он перестал ждать подключения, так? Следовательно при завершении рабочего потока операционной системой возникнет исключение и приложение упадет. Вот пример, как это объехать https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1230878/373567

Comment: @aepot мне все равно, это не мне нужно.