# Как передавать данные между двумя приложениями на С++ и С# без записи в файл

Tags: c#, c++, websocket

Всем привет.
Есть 2 приложения, одно на C# и одно на C++
Приложение на C# генерирует число около 500 раз в секунду и выводит его на экран.
Как передать это число в приложение на С++?
Записывать в файл не вариант. Приложения оба на одной локальной машине запущены.

сделать вебсокет клиент-сервер? Или есть еще варианты, какие-то технологии?

UPD.: ОС - Windows 10

Comment: Операционная система какая?

Comment: можно использовать сокеты (вебсокеты это просто очень высокоуровневая обертка), пайпы. Да хоть через общую память

Comment: посмотрите https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37572938/stream-data-from-c-to-c-sharp-over-shared-memory через общую память

Comment: `Windows` - Memory Mapped File или Named Pipe. Я бы предпочел даже второе ([C#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1230878/373567), [С++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26561604/12888024)).

Comment: Нужно немного уточнить, нужно именно передавать Сгенерированные числа как поток и все их держать как историю или только последнее число? В первом случае нормальным вариантом будут только пайпы (System.IO.Pipes), а во втором это общая память или удалённый вызов через COM-механизмы https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/interop/interop-marshaling Вебсокет/сокет клиент-сервер - это очень простой и быстрый путь, но сильно перегруженный. К тому-же что вы будете делать если порт, который вы определили константой - окажется занят? Писать номер порта в промежуточный файл и потом искать его?

Comment: Возможен и продвинутый вариант: комбинация разделяемой памяти и семафора с именем. Тогда у вас будет и синхронизация, и скорость, и минимальное использование ресурсов. Только про Thread.Sleep не забывайте чтобы семафор не лупил.

Comment: А просто пайп? Один выводит в стандартный вывод, второй оттуда читает...