# при запуске программы уже запущенная копия программы должна закрываться.C#

Tags: c#

Нужно чтобы при запуске программы уже запущенная копия закрывалась. Что-то вроде Mutex только наоборот

Comment: И что именно не получается? И самое главное - зачем? Это же не логично заставлять ОС грузить то же самое приложение заново в оперативу, когда есть уже загруженное.

Comment: ну я не знаю как это зделать. ну мне нужно чтобы приложение так работало

Comment: Ну, например так https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1230878/373567