# Найти в списке запущенных NET Core Application Windows/Linux

Tags: c#, .net-core, процесс

Столкнулся с проблемой. Не могу найти способ поиска в списке запущенных приложений NET Core Application.
У меня задача из одного приложения NET Core закрыть другое приложение NET Core.
Запускается приложение: dotnet test.dll

Поиск методом System.Diagnostics.GetProcesses() не работает.
Я так понимаю, что если способ есть, то он отличается в Windows и в Linux. Я буду использовать и ту и другую ОС.

Помогите пожалуйста решить проблему, если это вообще возможно.
Спасибо!

Comment: Автор обоих приложений вы, или стороннее приложение? Если первое, то `Mutex` и [вот так](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1230878/373567).

Comment: Как именно используете `GetProcesses()`? Покажите код. Возможно, не учитываете регистр символов или расширение.

Comment: Я вообще все процессы посмотрел, полученные методом GetProcesses(). Там есть процесс dotnet, на сколько я понимаю "внутри этого процесса" и запускается приложение NET Core.

Comment: `Запускается приложение: dotnet test.dll` .... `Там есть процесс dotnet` - ну выглядит логично

Comment: tym32167
 Так вот я и спрашиваю есть ли возможность внутри этого процесса (если можно так выразиться) найти свой и остановить?                                                                                          aepot написал способ при помощи Mutex. Он работает частично - закрыть процесс при помощи Mutex мне не удалось.