# Отказ в доступе к элементу массива процессов

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;    

namespace OS_Lab_1 name.
{
 internal class MyProcess
    {
        TimeOnly time;

      public TimeOnly Time
        {
            get { return time; }
            set { time = value; }
        }

        public void lifeTimeProcess()
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < Process.GetProcesses().Length; i++)
            {
                if (!(Process.GetProcesses()[i].HasExited))
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(5000);
                    lifeTimeProcess();
                }
                else Console.WriteLine("Время" + (Process.GetProcesses()[i].ExitTime - Process.GetProcesses()[i].StartTime));
            }
        }
       public void startProcessesFromFile()
        {
            String line;
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("C:\\Users\\Максим\\source\\repos\\OS_Lab_3\\OS_Lab_3\\config.txt");
            line = sr.ReadLine();

            while (line != null)
            {         
                    if (Char.IsDigit(line[0]))
                    {   
                    time = new TimeOnly(0, 0, int.Parse(line));
                    Console.WriteLine(Time + ":" + Time.Second);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    Console.WriteLine(line);
                    Process process = Process.Start(line);
                }
                line = sr.ReadLine();
            }
            sr.Close();
            lifeTimeProcess();

        }

        public void startExecutableFile(string path)
        {
            if (File.Exists(path))
            {
               Process process=Process.Start(path);
               
                if (!process.HasExited)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(5000);
                    process.Kill();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Файл не найден\n");
                Thread.Sleep(10000);
                startExecutableFile(path);
            }
              
        }
        void changeThreads()
        {
            StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader("C:\\Users\\Максим\\source\\repos\\OS_Lab_3\\OS_Lab_3\\input.txt");
            StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter("C:\\Users\\Максим\\source\\repos\\OS_Lab_3\\OS_Lab_3\\output.txt");

            String line= streamReader.ReadLine();
            while (line != null)
            {
                streamWriter.WriteLine(line);
                line = streamReader.ReadLine();
            }
            streamReader.Close();
            streamWriter.Close();
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MyProcess myProcess = new MyProcess();
            myProcess.startProcessesFromFile();
            //  Console.WriteLine(myProcess.Time+":"+myProcess.Time.Second);

            //  myProcess.startExecutableFile("C:\\Program Files\\WinRAR\\WinRAR.exe");
            myProcess.changeThreads();
           
        }
    }
   
}
```

У меня возникла проблема с доступом к массиву процессов.Я считываю из config.txt имя процесса и максимальное допустимое время выполнения.И запускаю процессы в функции startProcessesFromFile.После запуска всех процессов я вызываю функцию lifeTimeProcess,где я ожидаю пока пользователь завершит процесс.Но я не могу получить доступ к элементу массива процессов.
Исключение:

```
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: "Отказано в доступе."
```

Все процессы запускаются.В данном случае у меня открылся блокнот и проводник виндовс.

Comment: Попробуйте запустить Visual Studio / .exe файл от имени администратора и прописать явно разрешения на чтение, запись и изменение для текущего пользователя в настройках безопасности всех использующихся файлов и папок

Comment: Можно [обмениваться между процессами данными](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1230878/373567), и не мучить операционную систему поллингом списка процессов.

Comment: ну я поставил разрешения для пользователей на всем моем диске,но там для некоторых папок он не смог выдать разрешение.и когда я запустил студию,то исключение не пропало

Comment: Что за лютая хтонь в `lifeTimeProcess`? Вот это: `Process.GetProcesses()` - должно вызываться всего раз. Каждое ваше обращение `[i]` может выдавать разные процессы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В методе `lifeTimeProcess` четыре(!) раза вызывается `Process.GetProcesses()`. Какждый раз вызвращается **новый** массив процессов. Они могут различаться при каждом вызове. Их количество тоже может быть разным. Потому что в операционной системе постоянно запускаются и останавливаются какие-нибудь процессы. Кстати, всего их, навскидку, будет сотни две.

Даже в этой строке: `Process.GetProcesses()[i].ExitTime - Process.GetProcesses()[i].StartTime` свойства `ExitTime` и `StartTime` могут быть взяты в итоге у **разных** процессов.

По крайней мере, для начала, следует вызывать этот метод всего один раз:

```
// Внимание! Нерабочий код!
void lifeTimeProcess()
{
    var processes = Process.GetProcesses();

    for (int i = 0; i < processes.Length; i++)
    {
        if (!processes[i].HasExited)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            lifeTimeProcess();
        }
        else Console.WriteLine("Время" + (processes[i].ExitTime - processes[i].StartTime));
    }
}
```

Но это не спасёт от ошибки "Отказано в доступе". Метод `GetProcesses()` вернёт **все** процессы ОС, в том числе системные. Естественно, доступ к ним запрещён. Да он вам и не нужен.

Вам же нужно дождаться завершения тех процессов, которые вы сами запустили? Тогда фильтруйте их по названию. В частности, есть метод `Process.GetProcessesByName`.

Но лучше сохранить запускаемые процессы в список, а потом использовать этот список.
Сделайте в своём классе `MyProcess` поле:

```
private List<Process> processes = new List<Process>();
```

Когда запускаете процесс, сохраняйте его в этот список:

```
Process process = Process.Start(...);
processes.Add(process);
```

Далее используйте его в методе `LifeTimeProcess`:

```
foreach (var process in processes)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: понял , спасибо