# CallContext в .Net 6.0 Core — как обмениваться данными между разными инстансами одного приложения не через файловую систему?

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть приложение написаное на WPF. Возникла необходимость обмениваться данными между разными инстансами этого приложения. Сразу вспомнил про System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.CallContext, но приложение написано на .Net 6.0 Core. Не хотелось бы для этого использовать файловую систему в т.ч. Settings файлы. Как лучше сделать?

Comment: Named Pipes....

Comment: Не пойму, почему был закрыт этот мой вопрос как дублирующий, при том что в ответе на который дана ссылка, отвечают совершенно на другой вопрос, а не на мой. Мой вопрос не про контроль того, чтобы был запущен только один инстанс моего приложение, а совсем про другое, а именно — про то, как обмениваться между инстансами данными .Net Core приложениях. Так, как это делается не в Core приложениях посредством CallContext.

Comment: Ок переоткрыл. Но names pipes есть в core приложениях. И там ответ как раз про обмен данными, как поднять сервер сообщений и как передать данные через канал связи между приложениями. Будьте внимательней, суть там не в названии вопроса, а в коде ответа. Вот ссылка, чтоб не потерялась https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1230878/373567

Comment: Спасибо! А то что в том сообщении есть и про то, что нужно мне, я действительно упустил из виду. Сейчас буду разбираться. Если Вы действительно полностью уверены что я там найду решение которое мне необходимо, то если считаете нужным, можете все-таки закрыть мой вопрос. Еще раз Спасибо!