# C# Взаимодействие двух программ

Tags: c#

У меня такая задача, есть программа на C# .Net 4.7.2 которая работает в виде службы windows, к ней необходимо написать плагин (с этим проблем нету), но изначально служба не имеет интерфейса и вызывать окна в ней нельзя, из этого появляется необходимо написать ПО для взаимодействия с плагином.
Как или чем, налаживать связь между моим ПО и отдельным моим плагином?

Comment: Named Pipe например

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1230878/373567

Comment: @AlexF WCF как и gRPC - это скорее когда сервер и клиент на разных машинах. Юзать HTTP для коммуникаций внутри одной машины при наличии более подходящих инструментов - не очень эффективно.

Comment: За эфективность не скажу, но юзал grpc пару раз для ipc и это намного удобней чем сырые пайпы. А если брать старую версию от гугла, то у неё есть транспорт на пайпах.