# Процессы и события с#

Tags: c#, wpf, события, процесс

Мне нужно сделать программу, в которой один процесс дожидается нажатия клавиши или кнопки на окне и сообщает об этом другому процессу.Второй процесс должен дождаться события и вывести сто разноцветных фигур.С выводом фигур проблем нет.Делаю в проекте WPF.А вот с передачей информацией между процессами проблемы.Не знаю,как это можно сделать.В крайнем случае можно сделать потоки вместо процессов,если там проще это сделать.

Comment: Вы понимаете различие процесса и потока?

Comment: [Межпроцессное взаимодействие](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Межпроцессное_взаимодействие) - выбирайте любой подходящий способ.

Comment: Процесс это выполняемая программа,а поток это набор инструкций.В процессе должен запускаться файл,а в потоке можно запустить функцию.Я понимаю что это вообще разные вещи, но тут я могу отклониться немного от задания и сделать потоки, не столь принципиально.

Comment: [How to: Use Anonymous Pipes for Local Interprocess Communication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/how-to-use-anonymous-pipes-for-local-interprocess-communication)

Comment: А хотя мне же надо чисто через событие сделать.Оно,как я понял,тоже входит в межпроцессное взаимодействие.В таком случае что можно сделать?У меня по идее уже присутствует в WPF процесс главного окна.А в другом процессе что запускать?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1230878/373567 это про процессы, разные приложения. А с потоками вы точно не перепутали?

Comment: Ну к потокам тоже можно применять мьютекс,семафор и прочее.Для демонстрации работы,впринципе,потоки тоже сгодились бы.но мне тут именно через событие нужно передать информацию от процесса к процессу,а я не знаю как это сделать

Comment: Событие - это одно. Передача информации между процессами - это другое. В одном процессе произошло событие нажатия на кнопку - вы его обработали и передали информацию в другой процесс.