# Обмен данными между двумя приложениями, C#

Tags: c#, ipc

Есть два приложение: **Первое** (браузерное) и **Второе** (консольное). **Первое** получает из своей вьюхи 2 числа, отдаёт их во **Второе**. **Второе** их складывает и возвращает в **Первое**, которое выводит результат в браузер.

C `IPC` (`inter-process communication`) ранее не сталкивался, поэтому передачу в консольное приложение сначала сделал через `MemoryMappedFile`, работает. Потом понял, что обратно результат не передать, надо использовать другую технологию, выбрал каналы.

Решил (1) оставить работающий `MemoryMappedFile` для обработку 'туда' (2) добавить `Threading.Channels` - для обработки 'обратно'.

В итоге должно получиться три этапа:

1. Первое (браузерное) приложение:
   Ввели 2 числа в форму, передали в контроллер, тот их принял и передал в `MemoryMappedFile`.
2. Второе (консольное) приложение:
   Получило данные из `MemoryMappedFile`, обработало, [**ТУТ ЗАСТРЯЛ**] отдаёт результат в канал (т.е. выступает как `Producer`, если в терминах каналов)
3. Первое (браузерное) приложение:
   Контроллер ловит данные из канала (`Consumer`), результат возвращает в представление.

Застрял на реализации каналов. Как сделать?
Или, может быть, всё вообще не так и надо полностью переделывать?

Методы из контроллера первого (браузерного) приложения `Core MVC`.

```
// принимает данные из View, отдаёт в MemoryMappedFile, работает
    public IActionResult PassData(IndexModel model)  
    {
        string NumberI = model.NumberI;
        string NumberJ = model.NumberJ;
        string result = (NumberI + " " + NumberJ);
        char[] message = result.ToCharArray();
        int size = message.Length;
        MemoryMappedFile sharedMemory = MemoryMappedFile.CreateOrOpen("MemoryFile", size * 2 + 4);
        using (MemoryMappedViewAccessor writer = sharedMemory.CreateViewAccessor(0, size * 2 + 4))
        {
            writer.Write(0, size);
            writer.WriteArray<char>(4, message, 0, size);
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

// Должен принимать результат по каналу из второго приложения 
// Не работает 
static async Task MyChannel()  
{
    Channel<int> unboundedChannel = Channel.CreateUnbounded<int>(new UnboundedChannelOptions
    {
        AllowSynchronousContinuations = true
    });
    ChannelReader<int> reader = unboundedChannel;
    int valueFromChannel = await reader.ReadAsync();
    await reader.Completion;
    //return valueFromChannel; 
}
```

Второе (консольное) приложение, `Program.cs`

```
  static int TopLevelVar = 0;

// ловит данные в  MemoryMappedFile из первого приложения 
// Работает
static void Main()   
{
    char[] message;
    int size;
    MemoryMappedFile sharedMemory = MemoryMappedFile.OpenExisting("MemoryFile");
    using (MemoryMappedViewAccessor reader = sharedMemory.CreateViewAccessor(0, 4, MemoryMappedFileAccess.Read))
    {
        size = reader.ReadInt32(0);
    }
    using (MemoryMappedViewAccessor reader = sharedMemory.CreateViewAccessor(4, size * 2, MemoryMappedFileAccess.Read))
    {
        message = new char[size];
        reader.ReadArray<char>(0, message, 0, size);
    }
    string charsStr = new string(message);
    string[] splitted = charsStr.Split(' ');
    int NumI = Convert.ToInt32(splitted[0]);
    int NumJ = Convert.ToInt32(splitted[1]);
    int result = NumI + NumJ;
    //string ResultString = result.ToString();
    //Console.WriteLine(ResultString);
    TopLevelVar = result;
}


// Тут застрял - надо передать TopLevelVar в канал
public static async Task WriteToChannel()    
{
    Channel<int> unboundedChannel = Channel.CreateUnbounded<int>(new UnboundedChannelOptions
    {
        AllowSynchronousContinuations = true
    });
    ChannelWriter<int> writer = unboundedChannel;
    var writerTask = Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        int objectToWriteInChannel = TopLevelVar;
        await writer.WriteAsync(objectToWriteInChannel);
    });
    await writerTask;
    writer.Complete();
}
```

Comment: Очень странная задумка. Если у вас часть логики находится на сервере, а часть на клиенте, то делайте прямое соединение через соккеты или их аналоги, например, SignalR, где вы авторизовываете клиента, и можете как серверу отправить запрос, так и сервер может отправить запрос вам. Если вам нужна частичная связь, то можете пойти в сторону gRPC, где сервер может вызывать у клиента нужную логику, а обратно уже можно по средствам API передавать данные. Но каналы с сервером, и хранение в памяти... Сервер вообще не должен про клиента знать, а вы их так связываете... Или "браузерное" это не сервер?

Comment: `Threading.Channels` для IPC непригодны. Возьмите пайпы (Pipes).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ
не уверен, что в этом случае вообще можно говорить об архитектуре сервер-клиент.

Comment: `в этом случае` - в каком? Только вы знаете какой там "случай", ибо я лично вижу лишь "есть браузер и есть консоль", а также вижу "передали в контроллер", а это в моем понимании именно сервер и два клиента. Если у вас там веб морда у десктоп приложения (а-ля Electron), то об этом стоит прямо говорить в вопросе.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1230878/373567 - готовый пример на базе Named Pipe. MMF предназначен для шары большого объема данных, он не очень удобен для обмена сообщениями.

Comment: MMF делается обмен в обе стороны без проблем. Вот тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70758093/memorymappedfilesecurity-missing-in-net-6/72976941#72976941 есть дополнительная информация. Делал обмен между приложением и службой Windows. Приложение пишет в MMF и даёт службе пользовательскую команду. Служба по команде читает из файла, обрабатывает, пишет обратно в файл. Чтобы не использовать дополнительный механизм для оповещения приложения, оно читает ответ из файла просто через время задержки. А так в WIndows есть сообщения, которыми можно воспользоваться для извещения другого приложения.

Comment: В итоге сделал через MMF в обе стороны, с задержкой. Не очень хороший вариант, хотел его избежать. Намного лучше было бы с прослушиванием событий на pipe, но не успеваю уже. Ребята rotabor, aepot, AlexanderPetrov, EvgeniyZ всем большое спасибо!

Comment: А в Винде есть аналог inotify?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> MMF делается обмен в обе стороны без проблем
> ```

Ну проблема в необходимости пинка получателю информации. Вот если бы была возможность простого слежения за файлом по аналогии с файлом на харде (тот же filesystemwatcher) то было бы счастье.
А так или пинать, или писать, например, собственный асинхронный метод проверки содержимого. И как только что-то изменилось - действовать.